# Custom radio buttons not working properly iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created 2 custom radio buttons, but the selection is not working properly. When I press the 1st radio button, it does not get selected but when I press it again or if I press the 2nd radio button then the first radio button responds.

This is the code in .h file. I am using the NSString to store the btn values when selected, for e.g. if 1st is selected then "Male" will be stored in the NSString.

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *radio1;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *radio2;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * radioString1;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * radioString2;
    -(void)radioBtnSelected:(UIButton *)btn;
```

The code in the .m file

```
@synthesize radio1;
@synthesize radio2;
@synthesize radioString1;
@synthesize radioString2;
```

Creating the custom radio buttons in the "viewDidLoad". Using tags to differentiate between the two radio buttons

```
//radio btns
radio1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 253, 20, 20)];

//setting the tag of btn, to switch between the two
radio1.tag = 0;

//setting the on and off background image
[radio1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioButton-Unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[radio1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioButton-Selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

//setting the action event, on what to do when the btn is clicked
[radio1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radioBtnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:radio1];

radio2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 253, 20, 20)];
radio2.tag = 1;
[radio2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioButton-Unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[radio2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioButton-Selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[radio2 addTarget:self action:@selector(radioBtnSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:radio2];
```

I tried to inspect the problem using break points and I found out that, when I click on the radio button the first time, it does not complete the "if statement" and jumps to the "else" part, but when I select the first radio again, then it completes the "if statement"

```
-(void)radioBtnSelected:(UIButton *)btn{

switch ([btn tag]) {
    case 0:
        if ([radio1 isSelected] == YES) {
            [radio1 setSelected:NO];
            [radio2 setSelected:YES];
            radioString1 = @"Male";
            NSLog(@"%@", radioString1);
        }
       else{
            [radio1 setSelected:YES];
            [radio2 setSelected:NO];
            radioString1 = @"";
        }
        break;

     case 1:
        if ([radio2 isSelected] == YES) {
            [radio1 setSelected:YES];
            [radio2 setSelected:NO];
            radioString2 = @"Female";
            NSLog(@"%@", radioString2);
        }
        else{
            [radio1 setSelected:NO];
            [radio2 setSelected:YES];
            radioString2 = @"";
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not compare **BOOL** to **YES**

```
if ([radio1 isSelected] == YES)
```

instead use this form

```
if ( [radio1 isSelected] )
```

***Description:***

BOOL is eight bits variable, so it can hold value from -128 through 127. Variable represents untruth with zero value and truth with non-zero values. There are 255 different versions of truth.

YES and NO macros have integer equivalents 1 and 0 accordingly.

Read more about differences between **BOOL** and **bool** [here](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/)